# Method or Data Member Not found for every control or event

Tags: ms-access, vba

Got a weird problem. I was debugging some code for a form and everything was working as intended for the most part when suddenly I began to get a "Method or Data Member Not Found" for every event of my form. It's like my form suddenly does not recognize any of my controls or events. I have all of my methods properly closed and did not rename any controls.

Any ideas on what would be the root of "Method or Data Member Not Found" for every single control with an event?

Thanks

Comment: The database could be corrupted.  You could try to create a new database and import everything into it.

Comment: I've had this happen to me once before.  It fixed itself when everyone got out of the database and re-opened it.

Comment: It might be just the form, try copying the controls to a new form. Also decompile.

Comment: Developing on an unsplit database seems to lead to more corruption, but that may be just my experience.

Comment: You know - it was actually from a typo on one control. After I created a new database and imported everything, it gave me an actual error message for that control only. I really don't know why this would have affected all other controls and events on the old db, but I scrapped it and am now using an aacdb rather than mdb.

Comment: Don't forget to backup, compact and repair and decompile fairly regularly when you are developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing into a fresh database as talbright suggested gave me more descriptive error messages.

A fresh import, compact&repair, and renaming of appropriate control fixed the problem from occuring. As Remou suggested, regular maintenance can help prevent these sorts of problems.

edit for future readers: This problem occurred while using a shared front end file. So don't do that if possible.

Comment: +1 for adding the note re: shared front-ends, but "don't do that if possible" should be replaced with "don't **ever** do that".

Comment: @GordThompson Very true, but sometimes it's hard to avoid when lots of the files are undergoing constant development. I tend to place the newest front ends on the drive and tell people to COPY IT TO YOUR DESKTOP AND USE THAT, but they usually end up making a shortcut:( I really need to look into this AutoFE Updater that I've seen mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that any `MISSING:` reference can make the simplest of code fail.

Check in the visual basic window

Menu Tools -> References

[image: look down the checked refences to see if any are MISSING]

look down the checked refences to see if any are MISSING

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same error by renaming text and combo boxes something not so close to a concatenated Table & Field string. Actually just prepended those names with "tbx" and "cbx".